# Show a message on top of a UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, interface-builder, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which is backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I would like to display a message on top of the list, e.g. "Showing items filtered by XYZ". I tried inserting a `UIView` with a `UILabel` in it on top of the screen in the IB, but it doesn't seem to work. Is this even possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use header on the table view, your can add a custom header on the top of your UITableView.

Implement this method :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *myCustomView = [UIView alloc] init];
    //Add your label on myCustomView 

    return myCustomView;

}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I also had to implement this method in UITableViewDelegate to override the default header height: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your .xib's owner is subclassing from a UITableViewController, try changing it to a UIViewController that has a UITableView and your UILabel as subviews in IB.